# Forces acting on particles

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

What is the difference between air resistance/friction force and up thrust force?
I always think that air friction is the same as up thrust but it does not seem that way.

Answer (score 1):

Upthrust on an object in a medium (such as air) is the difference between its weight in a vaccum and weight in the medium.

An object doesn't need to be moving to experience upthrust, but it needs to moving relative to the air to experience air resistance.

Answer (score 1):

Air resistance is the drag acting opposite to the relative motion of any object with respect to the air or any fluid not only air. This depends on velocity of the moving object. The more fast the object the more is the drag. This can exist between two fluid layers (or surfaces) or a fluid and a solid surface.

Upthrust also known as Buoyancy is an upward force by a fluid on an object immersed in it. The pressure increases from top to bottom in a column of fluid. The upward force is because of the difference in pressure on the top and bottom part of the fluid which results in a net upward force.